# Error in c# Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 21

Tags: c#

I get an error in a c# project.

I am trying declare and initialize an array of int and provide initial values to it.

I'm trying the following code:

```
internal static int[, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,] int_17 = new int[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
```

and the error appears here:

```
 int index = 1;
 while (Class9.int_17[index] != num)
 {
      index++;
      if (index > 21)
      { 
         // some code here
      }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, but you do create an array with 21 dimensions. Is that what you want? If not - well, RTFM, array syntax.

Comment: why are you doing that? Provide more context

Comment: I *strongly* suspect you want `int[] int_17 = { 0, 1, 2, ..., 20 }`. I've never seen anything requiring a rectangular array with that many dimensions (whether that's 17 or 21...)

Comment: You have a lot of dimensions but are only accessing one of them. Perhaps it would help if you clarify your intentions so we can determine if you're trying to do the wrong thing.

Comment: try doing internal static int[] int_17 = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};

Comment: @Dhawalk: That won't compile either. You're trying to assign a rectangular array reference to a one-dimensional array variable.

Comment: that's why i wrote it in comment. anyways.. edited the comment... i haven't compiling this one too

Comment: @Dhawalk So you knew your answer was wrong so you posted it as a comment?  Why not just post the *right* answer...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you meant to do what you are doing.
you are trying to initialize a 21 dims array!!!

If you want an array to contain numbers between 0-20:

```
int[] arr = new int[21]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

### The declaration part:

**[,]** is for two dims array.

**[,,]** is for three, as so on.

### The initialization part :

`new int[sizeOfDim]` or `new int[sizeOfFirstDim,sizeOfSecondDim]`

If you want to provide initial values in the initialization part do it with the curly bracket as shown above.

Comment: +1. Note that "array to contain numbers between 0-20" may be more readable in form of `Enumerable.Range(0,21).ToArray()` - it is very not-reader-friendly to specify 20 numbers that should be in particular order and expect one to make sure all are ok.

Comment: I guess the values provided in the question are for making it clear what he was trying to do, so they are irrelevant . In case of this specific use- you are more then right.

Answer (score 0):

While your code you have may compile and not give you any warnings, you probably meant t create an array in a different fashion. The classic array syntax for initializing a populated array would be:

```
internal static int[] int_17 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

likewise, you could do this in a more programatic fashion by saying:

```
internal static int[] int_17 = new int[20];
for(int i = 1; i<=20; i++)
{
    int_17[i-1] = i;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is:

```
internal static int[] int_17 = new int [] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

. .  . . 

int index = 0; // the index must start with 0, not 1 as in your original code
while (Class9.int_17[index] != num)
{
    index++;
    if (index > 21) //0x21 is a hexadecimal number which means 33
    {
        ....
    ....
```